# Data determined by URI

Tags: database, codeigniter, uri

So at the moment, my CI website is formatted to take part of the URI, let's say an id, and find a result in the database from it to display on the page.

If I enter an id that is not in the database however, naturally I am going to get a database error. Is there a better way of protecting my URI's from direct db access, and, what would be the best method to tell the user that the URL they entered is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imo you should not only display a error, but also throw a 404 (or 301, depends on your application) for **SEO** reasons

a simple implementation:

**MY_Controller.php**

```
...
protected function error404()
{

    set_status_header(404);

    $data = array();

    $this->load->view('error404_view', $data);
}
```

**examplecontroller.php**

```
...
        $data = $this->Some_model->get_by_id($id);
        if (empty($data))
        {
            $this->error404();          
        }
        else
        {
            // your view here        
        }
...
```

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Yep I basically created a function in a model to check the page's id. I passed the database name to the function so it knows where to look, then redirected to a 404 error page. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your id is stored in $id. Then you can do something like this.

```
if() // if $id not found - depends how you are doing check
{
    $errorMsg = "Not found";
    $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMsg', $errorMsg );
    redirect('home'); //Redirect to the page which is always available and display flashdata with error message here
}
```

Comment: Now would that be best put in my controller or my view?

Comment: This should be in controller.

Comment: I normally use flashdata to display messages. It will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. So you can grab this flashdata on the page you redirect to and display message to user there. More information about flashdata is here - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Okay so I put it in, and I guess I need it to check if that id is in the database. But surely that would be slow, checking every time if the id exists in the database? What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Plus I would have to write a bunch of specialised code for each controller function.... and that doesn't sound appealing